# C# browser automation that will work on server

Tags: c#, browser-automation

I have been using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) for some browser automation and website testing. Recently I received a request to automate some task that needs to check a partner website for existence of some SKU (since they don't have a proper API) and confirm transaction.

I tried using WatiN, but since this runs on a server and on-demand, the server desktop is naturally locked at most times and the IE window does not open and the process is never run.

I am looking for an alternative to WatiN, which is preferably a .net library (not a must, but just makes things easier), does not require a logged in user and being free and open source is always nice.

Anyone have experience with this type of automation?

Comment: Do you need to render the site in a browser or would it do with just doing some http manually and checking/parsing the html?

Comment: There is no need to render the site, as long as the DOM is built and elements can be accessed and manipulated. Another requirement is the ability to submit forms.

Comment: You could still find certain elements and submit forms manually, as long as the site doesn't rely on js to do stuff. Might take a lot of work though.

Comment: @Chris - "Might take a lot of work though" - that is what I am trying to avoid. If I wanted low-level dirty code I would use something like the HTML Agility Pack. I'm looking for a higher level of abstraction, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) coupled with [PhantomJS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/phantomjs.exe/).

Selenium is similar in many ways to WaitN but it supports more browsers. PhantomJS is a headless browser and wrapped in a portable executable you can run from your web server.

Once you've added the NuGet packages, you will be able to instantiate a PhantomJS web driver and control a site without having to launch a full-fledged browser.

```
var driver = OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver();
```

We use this on build servers since the build agents are not logged in and won't be able to launch a normal browser process.

If you just need to check some HTML, you can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to make a request to the site, return the content response as a string and parse it.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this; Selenium documentation is available from [Selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Yes! Selenium + PhantomJS is exactly the combo I was looking for! About the WebClient, if I wanted to go low-level I could have used the HTML Agility pack. I want more abstraction. Thank you!